# Is there a way to prevent a form from being submitted if it is not auto completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning jquery and its awesome! Its very easy to do complex stuff but I'm unsure how to prevent someone from submitting a form(or warning them) if a autocomplete fails.

I  have a form on my site that gets autocompleted with existing data from my database and when they submit it provides info on that entry.  If they add something thats not in the database then my server will bounce them back to the form page and let them know of the error but I want to do something to warn them while they are filling out the form(before they submit the form).

Long story short, I know how to detect changes in the field but how can I detect(and prevent submission of form) when they the field is not in the database?  The two cases I'm thinking about is if there's a autocomplete for stock("ibm') and the user either types "ib"(before it fully completes) or "ibmm"(after it autocompleted).

Is there a jquery-ish easy way to detect if a field has not been fully resolved by autocomplete?

Any suggestions?

update:
As requested, here's my autocomplete code(basically just takes value in the search box and submits to a url called 'autocomplete'):

```
<script>
  $(function() {

    var cache = {},
      lastXhr;
    $( "#global-search-field" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 2,
      source: function( request, response ) {
      $(".message").empty()
        var term = request.term;
        if ( term in cache ) {
          response( cache[ term ] );
          return;
        }

        lastXhr = $.getJSON( "autocomplete", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
          cache[ term ] = data;
          if ( xhr === lastXhr ) {
            response( data );
            if ( data == 'no results found'){
              //alert(data);
              //$(".message").empty().append("not found!");
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });

  });
  </script>
```

Comment: A form is not a form without the *visible* **"SUBMIT"** button. Rather make if appear 'inactive', you know ... the gray font color and that stuff...

Comment: You can use jQuery for form validation (checking if required fields have some relevant content in them), but as far as I'm aware you can't use it to send and receive from the server. Don't take my word as gospel, I deduce this from my own research of jQuery and my quest to learn about it.

Comment: additional question: how you get values to autocomplete? by ajax or static array passed to autocomplete function?

Comment: @JerzyZawadzki as they type the result is being sent to a url I setup up that searches the result in a database and returns matches.  The jquery code is very simlair to the example here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache

Comment: ok - so my answer is ok - you can check remotely if value is on this list with ajax request on "onchange" event. If you would have static array you could check without ajax call - just checking this list

Comment: I'd be inclined to just allow the submit and return an appropriate error message if the entered value doesn't exist - you have to do server-side validation anyway in case the user is using dev tools to bypass your client-side validation. If you really feel you _must_ prevent submit then update your autocomplete callback to enable/disable the submit button depending on whether there was a match. Show your actual code rather than linking to something "similar".

Comment: @nnnnnn I updated the question with code. I do server side validation but I wanted to warn users in situations where they didn't complete the field or by mistake added something. I thought I should prevent the submit if I'm 100% sure the server will return a error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the form loaded with the button as disabled. As you are filling up the form, you have a running tally of flags (class=validation) to notify when the form is ready, then you can enable the button.

There is no sense in having a workable button that will attempt to call the server if you already know that it should fail if not all the information is ready.

The example in the bottom will work if you fill up all three boxes with text. You can signify controls by having each textbox with a class append text "required" in red font using the appendTo() in jquery.

As long as there is a class validation on the html element, it will be required, so as we are entering data, it will remove those validation classes:

```
<html>
  <head>
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("input[name^='test']").blur(function(){
             if ($(this).val() != "" && $(this).hasClass("validation")){
                $(this).removeClass("validation");
            }

            var check = $(".validation"); //checks to see if there is any more validation
            if (check.length == 0){
                $("#nowSubmit").prop("disabled", false);
            } else {
                $("#nowSubmit").prop("disabled", true);
            }
        });
    });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

<form>
<input id="control1" name="test" type="textbox" class="validation" />
<input id="control2" name="test" type="textbox" class="validation" />
<input id="control3" name="test" type="textbox" class="validation" />

<input id="nowSubmit" type="submit" value="Click Here" disabled="true"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/hSatZ/

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax request put on "onchange" event on autocomplete fields which would check if specific value is in db and will notify user about error if needed without submitting the form

Comment: I'm uber new to web dev. Just so I understand you correctly, I have two requests on this form..one is my normal autocomplete and the other is a ajax call on keyup or something that checks if its a exact match and if not notifies the user?

Comment: No reason to go back to the database... you've already cached the result.  If the user has selected something from autocomplete, it'll be in your cache.