# correct implementation of html form validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I wrote a simple piece of javascript to validate a checkbox group. The javascript works fine but implementing it correctly in html is proving difficult. My attempts either result in the form being sent anyway despite failed validation, or no submit button but everything else working ok. Is anyone able to help? thanks

```
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="pre_process.php">
        <input name="q" type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['q']; ?>" size="67"/>



<input type="submit" id="search_button" onclick= "chkChecks()" />
/////this line of code submits the form even when the javascript returns false

<input class="submit" type="button" onclick="chkChecks()" />
///this code works, doesn't send the form, but also takes away my nice shiny submit button

  ///////js code/////
    function chkChecks(){
isChecked=false

for(var i=0;i<document.forms["form1"]["SearchEngines[]"].length;i++){
if(document.forms["form1"]["SearchEngines[]"][i].checked){
isChecked=true
}
}

if(isChecked){
document.forms["form1"].submit()
}
else{
alert('Please select at least one Search Engine')
return false;
}

}
</script>
```

////also the part of the form being validated

```
<table width="200">
              <tr>
                <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="SearchEngines[]" value="Bing" id="SearchEngines_0" checked="checked" />
                  Bing</label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="SearchEngines[]" value="Blekko" id="SearchEngines_1" checked="checked"  />
                  Blekko</label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="SearchEngines[]" value="Entireweb" id="SearchEngines_2" checked="checked" />
                Entireweb</label></td>
              </tr>
```

Comment: can u show your js code?

Comment: Thanks for all the input guys but actually in the end all I needed to do was add a _value="Submit"_ to this line of code: _<input class="submit" type="button" onclick="chkChecks()" />_ and everything worked fine. Sorry if I didn't make the question clear. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

buttons will not submit a form - they don't do anything by default. They're generally used in conjunction with JavaScript as part of an AJAX application.

buttons will submit the form they are in when the user clicks on them, unless you specifiy otherwise with JavaScript.

check for isChecked variable is true or false, if it it false then do some check and make that variable true.

```
if(isChecked !== true) { 
    for(var i=0;i<document.forms["form1"] ["SearchEngines[]"].length;i++){  
       if(document.forms["form1"]["SearchEngines[]"][i].checked){
          isChecked=true 
       }
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply. I do need a button though. How would you suggest I proceed?

Comment: check for isChecked variable is true or false, if it it false then do some check and make that variable true.

if(isChecked !== true) {
  for(var i=0;i<document.forms["form1"]      ["SearchEngines[]"].length;i++){
if(document.forms["form1"]["SearchEngines[]"][i].checked){
 isChecked=true
}
}
}

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="submit" type="button" onclick="chkChecks()" />
```

Your function `chkChecks` may return false, but the actual handler created from an attribute is more like this:

```
function(event) {
    chkChecks();
}
```

It is better to use JavaScript to attach the event handler so the return value gets recognized:

```
document.getElementById("submitbutton").onclick = chkChecks;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out an answer I submitted here:

[Is there a way to prevent a form from being submitted if it is not auto completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571245/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-a-form-from-being-submitted-if-it-is-not-auto-complete/11571816#11571816)

It's how I've done form validations, there are also other tools as well that lets you do form validation too, but I figured why not do it myself, it's quicker and easier to manage.

You can either hardcode the validation class on an html yourself, or use jquery selectors on $(document).ready